# Xcode referencing old framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I'm trying to add the newest version of a framework to my Xcode project but can't seem to get Xcode to ignore the old one.

I have deleted the framework from the project and removed its listing in "Link Binary With Libraries" section. I then delete every instance of the old framework from my Mac and reset content and settings within the simulator. I clean my project and delete derived data. I then download the new version of the framework and drag and drop it in as usual. Everything appears to link up normally and the project builds without errors again. I go to the view that uses components from the new framework and a big "Trial Version" watermark is still on it and querying the frameworks own [getInfo] function returns the old framework version.

How do I go about completely deleting all reference to this framework? How is it still being built into the project when it no longer exists on my hard drive and I have wiped all the cached data from previous builds and linked a completely new framework from a different location?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It turned out to be the automatic framework searching that Xcode does locating the old framework in other versions of the project in other directories. What a headache.

Comment: Your answer doesn't quite help me out. How does one disable the automatic framework searching?

Comment: Any advice on how you fixed this would be appreciated?

Comment: This answer is not informative at all. Please add more detail to allow search-weary users find help here

Comment: Any suggestions for fixing this? Running into the same issue as well :/

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem to this and the fix was to look in the **Build Settings** for my project's target. Under **Framework Search Paths** was an old entry, pointing at an old copy of the framework. Removing this ensured that it used the latest framework.