# Xcode referencing old/removed frameworks, causing multiple interface declarations

Tags: xcode, frameworks, reference, duplicates

I'm getting interface re-declaration errors when I'm trying to build because xcode keeps referencing these old frameworks and headers that I've already removed from the project. I've sifted through my build phases and build settings and nothing seems to point to those files.

The funny thing is when xcode shows me my error and the line of code where the interface is supposedly redeclared, it won't show me any specific file when I click "Show in project navigator". However, if I ask it to "Show in finder", it instantly locates the file in my actual project directory (not xcode project directory). So this means that XCode is picking up unwanted frameworks that I've left in my project directory. I don't want XCode to do this. How do I clean this up? I've tried cleaning, restarting xcode and rebooting.

I looked at another SO discussion with the same problem but the user didn't give a proper solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759444/xcode-referencing-old-framework). How does one go about disabling the automatic framework searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case: have u checked FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS ? (Project Build Settings). I had a similar situation and found there references to the old paths which I removed and that did the trick.

*ADDITION:
As I moved my Xcode-Project to another location the compiler complained about "Library Search Paths" which where pointing to the old location. 
See => Build Settings, "Library Search Paths".*

Comment: As it stands, I keep the root of my project as a framework search path. I guess I should keep frameworks in a specific place, shouldn't I?