# XCode "File not found" error on parser, but compile fine

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am currently experiencing an annoyance which has been following me for a couple of days.

I integrated the `Facebook SDK` framework to an `iOS` project and it did work fine. I played with that Framework in a "mm" file of my project without any trouble. Lately, I decided to move all the Facebook specific code in an helper class that would deal with all the `Facebook` integration to make my code cleaner. Since then, the `XCode` parser has been complaining on the line that import the `framework SDK (FacebookSDK/Facebook.h)` that the file could not be found ...BUT... the error goes away when I am compiling. And then, as soon as I edit again the source file, the error comes back.

I have verified that the Framework path was properly set. Again, the parser has no issue when this import is in another mm file that is within the same project/folder. In addition, in the problematic class, as soon as I type the name of the Framework on the import line, the auto-complete will propose me that `FacebookSDK`.

- Rebooting XCode has no effect
- Cleaning the project didn't help
- Building the project fix the problem only until I edit the code again.

If you have clues, let me know!

Thanks,

Comment: May be that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255342/xcode-referencing-old-removed-frameworks-causing-multiple-interface-declaration/13261931#13261931

Comment: Thanks but the issue seems to be somewhere else. My framework search path are set properly.